# compile traceur at runtime during development

Tags: traceur

I'd like to compile ES6 at runtime during development of an angularjs app. I can run traceur before http-server starts up but this is tedious during development.

How do I set this up?

PS: I'm not using grunt at this stage. I think I might need to.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using traceur.require, [NodeApi](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/Node.js-API) , and [mocha-traceur] https://github.com/tucksen/mocha-traceur) on node side,  haven't tried on the browser yet. browserify should work or simply set compiler options to AMD?.

Have a look at [SystemJS](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) and [ES6ModuleLoader](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader), Also [practical-workflows](http://guybedford.com/practical-workflows-for-es6-modules), very informative and inspiring

Maps support at [traceur-source-maps](https://www.npmjs.org/package/traceur-source-maps) 
Or the already packaged maps-support

A little bit out of topic...  Another source of inpiration is [ATScript](https://github.com/angular/atscript-playground) playground , is transpiling , not on the fly